# Lift Problem: Encountering Log4J errors on Jetty:Run

Tags: scala, maven, lift

This problem seems to be quite common, but so far I have not found one single, useful solution.

I created a project using the `net.liftweb` blank archetype, version 2.2-M1, with maven 2. I just added one dependency, for H2 database, then also added some models and a DBVendor, like in the basic archetype. But I only ever get an exception like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager`.

Now, the logger is not vital for the entire program, bit when it comes to later problems with the mapper, I think I need the logs for debugging. I did a complete `mvn clean` and also deleted my `.m2` folder, but the problem persists.

Alternatively, whenever that error does not appear, I get another one, about a class missing aend thus the logger resorting to NOP. I got as far as to believe there's something wrong with my pom.xml, but I have now tried several variants with the log4j deps, all leading to no improvement.

I really hope you can help me here, Lift has been so far a series of undocumented error to me, way beyond the point where a little learning fun has morphed into a personal challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I put the solution here so others will find it:

Nowhere in the wiki it says that `Log.infoF` is deprecrated and will result in this error. The solution is quite simple, just replace it with `Schemifier.infoF _`, the line must look like this:

```
Schemifier.schemify(true, Schemifier.infoF _, User)
```

This works all right.